# How does R Locfit package calculate residuals

Tags: r, regression

I am using the following data using locfit regression, and am confused as to how the residuals are calculated.

http://pastebin.com/2iLaSxQD where it is stored as station.means (I call the text file January_raw_means.txt)

```
b <- read.table("./January_raw_means.txt", sep = "", header = TRUE)
station.means <- apply(b, 2, as.numeric) 
# Above is to store it as it is found within the original code.
```

I call locfit using this code:

```
locfit.regression <-   locfit(SD ~ Tmean + Elevation + Longitude + Latitude, 
                                 alpha = 0.3, 
                                 data = data.frame(station.means), maxk = 150)
```

And then call the residuals using this:

```
locfit.residuals <- residuals(locfit.regression)
```

The value at the first station (row in data) is:

```
> locfit.residuals[1]
[1] 2.529492
```

However, the fitted value is

```
> fitted(locfit.regression, type = "fit")[1]
[1] 18.68174
```

But the observed value is:

```
> station.means[1, "SD"]
[1] 26.62326
```

What is causing this discrepancy? I tried finding an observed value that would correspond to the one calculated from residual + fitted, but no dice. Even tried changing last couple of digits in case of rounding.

```
> 2.529492 + 18.68174
[1] 21.21123
> which(station.means == 21.21123)
integer(0)
> which((station.means >= 21.21120) & (station.means <= 21.21125))
integer(0)
```

What is going on?

Comment: Obviously `station.means[[1]]` is not a text file. Post code that creates an R data object, or upload the output of dput(station.mean[[1]] )`

Comment: Did as requested and made the variable names clearer.

Comment: Without seeing all of station.means[1, ] we cannot be sure that there is not an NA value in one of the covariates, so you may not really be comparing the correct values. Post more details of the data and model fit if you want us to believe you have found a bug worth investigating.

Comment: The issue was actually in the for loop which I had thought unnecessary to post. I'm editing the original question to highlight the issue (or should this better be posted as an answer?)

Comment: I for one am offended when an answer is posted where the question could not have been used to construct the answer. You should edit the question so it presents a problem capable of being answered. If you choose to then answer that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

(I understand this could have been arguably a comment but the clarity is enhanced with the "answer editing".) When I download that data and run the code I get this:

```
> locfit.residuals[1]
[1] -0.137262
> fitted(locfit.regression, type = "fit")[1]
[1] 26.76052
> station.means[1, "SD"]
      SD 
26.62326 
> station.means[1, "SD"]-fitted(locfit.regression, type = "fit")[1]
       SD 
-0.137262
```

So there really is no discrepancy on a current version of R and a compatible version of locfit:

```
> require(locfit)
Loading required package: locfit
locfit 1.5-9.1   2013-03-22
```

My comment above makes a plausible hypothesis (missing values in line 1) how this might occur in a larger dataset. It could be tested with:

```
station.means[ complete.cases(station.means), "SD"][1] - fitted(locfit.regression, type = "fit")[1]
```

The `complete.cases` function returns a logical vector as long as the number of rows in a dataframe and so is appropriate as a selection vector in the `i`-position of "[". So my best guess it that the question has little to do with "how" residuals are calculated but rather "which" residuals are actually there.